# When does the determiner "each" modify the plural noun?

Tags: meaning, determiners

> [A] We interviewed each individual **member** of the community. ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/individual_1))

For they have this meaning for ‘each’: “*used to refer to every one of two or more people or things*” in [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/each), isn’t it proper to write [B] “~each individual **members** of the community~” instead of the above clause? If there isn’t the typo, can we use either singular or plural after *each*, for *each* means the individual members of a set”(CGEL, p.378)? If it’s possible, how about their meaning difference?

If your answer is we can’t use the plural of [B] grammatically, what about this?:

> [C] to tell two or more people who have not met before what each other's **names** are ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/introduce))

For [C], *other's names* is the set, so it ought to be plural; but for [A] *the community* is the set, so we can't use plural form of members that is not part of the set?

Comment: Personally, I don't think [B] is possible. As for [C], I think it's '*each other's* names', not 'each *other's names*'. *Each other* refers to the two or more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Each** refers to every single member of a set *individually*, as opposed to **all**, which refers to all members of a set *together*. So the usage is as follows:

> I gave an apple to each **child** in the class.
>   I gave an apple to all **children** in the class.

As for your last sentence:

> to tell two or more people who have not met before what each other's names are

There are several names (two or more) belonging to the people (plural) that get introduced.
Here, each is not used on its own, but together with *other*. I agree with Fantasier that you could well use the singular here:

> They got to know each other's name.
>   They got to know each other's names.

They sound both OK to me, but the difference is in how you parse the sentence: do you read it as:

> They got to know the name of each other person. *Each [other's name]*
>   or
>   They got to know the names of the other people. _[Each other's] names

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, I think [C] is a typo. You don't use plurals with each as a pronoun. [C] should read "each others' names are" or "each other's name is". "Each" is a singular pronoun but you'll see it used as an adverb as well, which will show plural verbs: "We were allowed two tries each." That's from M-W (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/each).

For a more esoteric explanation of "each" as a quantifier, see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116662/each-pronoun-or-adverb

Answer (score 0):

If a speaker or author wants to use ***each*** with a plural noun there is a way

> We interviewed **each of the** community **members**

- ... **each of the** 46 member **countries** of the Council of Europe were...
- **Each of my** aunts have two children
- He saw **each of the** boys  once a week

Here the word *each* is being used a pronoun, not as a determiner. *Each* in the above examples stands for "every one individually" i.e. *every individual member*; *every individual aunt*; *every individual boy*.

> **Usage**
>   <sub>[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/each)</sub>
>
> When the pronoun is followed by an *of* phrase containing a plural noun
>   or pronoun, there is a tendency for the verb to be plural: ***Each*** of the
>   candidates **has**(or **have**) spoken on the issue.
>   Some usage guides
>   maintain that only the singular verb is correct, but plural verbs occur frequently even in edited writing.
>
> It is also sometimes said that the pronoun *each* must always be
>   referred to by a singular pronoun, but again actual usage does not
>   regularly observe this structure:
>
> - Each member of our garden club had **their** own special interests.
>
> In the most formal speech and writing, singular verbs and pronouns occur more frequently than plural:
>
> - Each member … had **his** own special interests.